# CGI Perl print mail not printing foreach loop

Tags: perl, cgi

I have the following piece of code in a large CGI perl mailer.

```
     print MAIL do{foreach my $m (@more){ print"URL: $m\n";}};
```

The array its pulling from is 
            @more = qw(google.com bob.com frank.com);

When I run the sendmail cgi script and get the email. This line is omitted! what gives? why am I not getting results? How can I fix it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The fact that this is CGI is a complete red herring here. One of the most useful skills a programmer can have is the ability to test scenarios which eliminate the factors that have no effect on the problem in hand.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
print MAIL do { expression }
```

… where the expression doesn't return anything useful for `do` to print to the MAIL file handle.

---

You also have:

```
foreach my $m (@more){
    print "URL: $m\n";
}
```

… where you aren't printing to the MAIL file handle.

---

Get rid of the `do` because it is nonsense. Print the URL to where you want to print it.

```
foreach my $m (@more){
    print MAIL "URL: $m\n";
}
```

---

Also consider using a [sensible module for sending email](http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-15/) (probably [Email::Sender::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender::Manual::QuickStart) instead of (presumably) piping stuff into the sendmail binary on your system directly.

Comment: Humm. Adding the foreach within print mail throws up an error cause it doesn't like it there.print MAIL "URL: $url\n";
foreach my $m (@more){ print MAIL "URL: $m\n";}};
print MAIL "Due Date: $date\n";

Comment: @user1937895 — I didn't say that you should put it inside the print. Replace **all** of the code in the question with the code in the third code block of this answer.

Comment: could you post an example of what you mean? it's not clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your line:

```
print"URL: $m\n"
```

Is printing the URL to `STDOUT`, not to the `MAIL` filehandle. And embedding that line in a `foreach` within a `do` isn't going to change that at all. All that's being printed to the `MAIL` filehandle is the return value from the `foreach` loop. And that (as you have seen) doesn't return anything.

I think you want to replace all of this code with:

```
print MAIL "URL: $_\n" for @more;
```

Or

```
print MAIL map { "URL: $_\n" } @more;
```

Comment: @user1937895: It's really no different to Quentin's answer. That would work too if you typed it correctly.

Comment: @user1937895: Also, I hope you take the time to understand why these solutions work and your original code didn't. Just cutting and pasting code from Stack Overflow is no way to build a career as a programmer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I understood your solution better than the one below. And, agree about cutting and pasting it's not the way of work. :)